# Proving that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} (x^2 +y^2 -x^3 y^3)/(x^2 +y^2) =1$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How can I go about proving that $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 +y^2 -x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2} = 1 ?$$

I checked some lines along $x, y$ and $x=y$ and it all gave $1$

Comment: Work in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In polar coordinates, this can be written as

$$1 - r^4 \cos^3 \theta \sin^3 \theta$$

and $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$ is equivalent to taking $r \to 0$.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution without polar coordinate:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 +y^2 -x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} 1- \frac{x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2}$$

To show $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2} = 0$ is equivalent to show $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} |\frac{x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2}| = 0 $:

Since $$0 \leq |\frac{x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2}| = \frac{|x|^3 |y|^3}{x^2 +y^2}   \leq^{[1]} \frac{|x|^3 |y|^3}{2|x||y|} = \frac{|x|^2 |y|^2}{2} $$

Where the inequality $[1]$ is with [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

By [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), $ 0 \leq \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} |\frac{x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2}| \leq \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{|x|^2 |y|^2}{2} = 0$.

So $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} |\frac{x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2}| = 0 $ which means $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2} = 0 $

Answer (score 0):

The first step,

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 +y^2 -x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} 1- \frac{x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2}$

Now study this and find $a$

$1-a=1-\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2}$

$a=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2}$

$\frac {1}{a}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 +y^2}{x^3y^3} $

$=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{x^2}{x^3 y^3}+\frac{y^2}{x^3 y^3}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{1}{xy^3}+\frac {1}{x^3y}=\infty$

Then $a$ must be $0$

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 +y^2 -x^3 y^3}{x^2 +y^2} = 1-a = 1$